# Surrounding try catch block around require keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a function in one of my files that the user can call with 2 parameters. These parameters are then used to construct a file path and if a file exists in that path then it should get that, else it should resort into a default file.

```
export const formImporter = (book, author) => {

  const importedFile = require(`../../chapter/page/${book}/${author}.jsx`).default
    || require(`../../chapter/page/common/${author}.jsx`).default;

  return importedFile; };
```

These files are functional react components. The problem is that I can't surround this with a try catch and this method doesn't work as it fails on the first case and does not bother trying the with the second case.

Essentially, I'd like for it to check if the path with the `book` and `author` exists. If not, then default to the `author` path.

Answer (score 1):

The `try/catch` method should work fine, if you add a `finally` block. A tiny snippet to illustrate how it may work:

```js
let foo;
const bar = "bar";

const tryCatchFinally = ( foo, bar ) => {
  try {
    foo.someProperty; // will throw an error since foo is undefined
  }
  catch ( error ) {
    console.log( "oh no an error occurred" );
    console.error( error );
  }
  finally {
    console.log( "...but I continue to run anyway" );
    console.log( bar ); // error is caught, however I can still execute something
    
    return bar;
  }
}

tryCatchFinally( foo, bar );
```

So in your case it would probably look something like this:

```
let importedFile;
const formImporter = ( book, author ) => {
  try {
    importedFile = require(`../../chapter/page/${book}/${author}.jsx`).default
  }
  catch ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
  }
  finally {
    if ( !importedFile) {
      importedFile = require(`../../chapter/page/common/${author}.jsx`).default;
    }

    return importedFile;
  }
}
```

Comment: `finally` is going to run even if there is no error, It will overwrite `importedFIle` as `author` every time, You should add a check there to see if `importedFIle` is a falsy value before you assign `author` to it